# From which version of Android api can I develop a scrollable app widget?

Tags: android, android-appwidget, scrollable

I like the scrollable Calendar App Widget (see picture), and I want to develop a similar scrollable widget for my application. But I'm not sure from which version of Android api (or platform) can I develop  a scrollable app widget? 
Any ideas?
Thank you so much!
[image]

Comment: If you mean a launcher screen widget, I believe this is not a function of the OS, but a function of the launcher itself. I've seen many widgets which were scrollable on certain non-default launchers only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am bluffed as I remember that ui controls (a.k.a widgets outside of the android world) were limited to a small number of classes (textview, imageview, and some others).

But the [android widget guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/appwidgets/index.html) seems to have been updated and you can now use [quite a lot of classes](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/appwidgets/index.html#CreatingLayout) including listviews. So I guess you can really develop a scrollable widget for android using this class without problems now.

Could someone confirm that there has been an update ?

---update ---
The method [setScrollPosition is available in the class RemoteViews](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RemoteViews.html#setScrollPosition%28int,%20int%29) only from android version 11.

Comment: Thank you so much! Seems that the scrolling list was only introduced from API 11.